# how to use kmeans on a hsv matrix

Tags: matlab, k-means, reshape, hsv

I am trying to use kmeans clustering only on the `h` matrix (from the original picture) and I am having trouble with the size of the matrix that I use with kmeans. I know that I need to reshape it , but noting I tried works.
Here is what I tried :

```
x = imread('4.jpg');
hsv=rgb2hsv(x);
H=c(:,:,1);
[m,n]=size(H);
X = reshape(H,[m,n,3]);
X = double(squeeze(X));
IDX = kmeans(double(H),3);
```

I get the error:

> to reshape the number of elements must not change.

Please help,
Thank you!

Comment: What's the purpose of the `reshape` and `squeeze` lines. I think it should work without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note your reshape will not work because the original size is m*n and your are trying to reshape into something with a size of m*n*3. You can't change the size with reshape.

This works:

```
x = imread('peppers.png');
hsv=rgb2hsv(x);
H=hsv(:,:,1); %******H=c(:,:,1);
[m,n]=size(H);
figure(1), imshow(H);
%X = reshape(H,[m,n,3]);
%X = double(squeeze(X)); 
IDX = kmeans(double(H(:)),3);  % NOTE change to this line
H = reshape(IDX,[m,n]);
figure(2), imagesc(H)
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help!
I have another question , I need to take the result of the kmeans (IDX) and go over the H matrix and replace every picsel  with the value that kmeans gave to it : 1 or 2 or 3.
I tried writing :
H(IDX == 1) = 0;
H(IDX == 2) = 100;
H(IDX == 3) = 255;
But it doesn’t replace all the matrix.,Just part of it.
Actually my  purpose is to separate the picture into clusters using kmeans but not on the original picture. Only on the H matrix.
Any ideas?

Comment: @user2339198 You get the indices into the image just by reshaping H. Also, if you find a post helpful, it is a good idea to up-vote or accept it.